# How to group dates in pivot table day wise?

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table

I want to present my data like this:
[image: 1]

My dataset looks like this:
[image: 2]

I tried group selection in pivot table tools but couldn't get the results I want. I could only get this:
[image: 3]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you set on using a pivot table? An alternative is using formulas such as the following. First, we'll add three new columns to your data.

```
Cell E3 formula:  =MONTH(A3)

Cell F3 formula:  =DAY(A3)

Cell G3 formula: =C3*D3
```

Drag 'em down.

Next, Column I has values 1 through 31. I input just the first 9 below. Columns J and on will have your 12 months. Using row 1 as the numeric month value, which we'll reference in the following formula.

```
Cell J3 formula: =IF(SUMIFS($G:$G,$E:$E,J$1,$F:$F,$I3)=0,"",SUMIFS($G:$G,$E:$E,J$1,$F:$F,$I3))
```

If the sum is 0, then it will return a blank. If you don't mind showing 0, then just remove the IF part of the formula. Drag it across and down, and you're done.

Finally add your conditional formatting.

[image]

Comment: The SUMIFS formula is basically looking up multiple criteria in a range. (sum range, criteria1 range, criteria 1, criteria 2 range, criteria 2 and so on if needed). Let's look at cell J3. We're summing the values in column G where the Month (value of 1 in cell J1) is found in column E, and also where the Day (value of 1 in cell I3) is found in column F. Special note: If you happen to have multiple rows fitting this criteria, then it will sum them all.  If this answer solves your problem, please approve, thanks.